# Delegate in not working on dynamically added elements

Tags: jquery

I have problem with delegate. Main problem is, that delegate is not working on dynamically created element.

```js
$('.menu').delegate('> li', 'click', function() {
  var thisId = this.id;
  alert(thisId);
});

$('#but').click(function() {
  $('#2').append('<ul><li id="new">yyy</li></ul>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
  <li id="1"><a>xxx</a>

  </li>
  <li id="2"><a>xxx</a>

  </li>
  <li id="3"><a>xxx</a>

  </li>
  <li id="4"><a>xxx</a>

    <ul class="menu">
      <li id='old'>old</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<button id="but">add</button>
```

Here you can see example of vertical menu with one submenu by default. Next is here button, that is adding submenu. Next I have simple delegate function, that is working on click and is returning id of clicked element. Problem occurs, when I add new submenu by #but button and try to click on it, because I will get Id of parent element only and not id of element and parent as it is with non dynamically added ul (as you can see at the end of html source). So how to edit my script to 'return only one id(id of clicked element only not of clicked and parent) and make it work on dynamically added elements?'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless it is purely for additional styling, your example does not need `.menu` on its sub-menus.

You just need to target all LIs within the top `.menu` (with `li`) and not just child LIs (you have `> li`). You also need to stop the click propagating to the parent (otherwise it will fire twice - on the `LI` clicked  & then again on the grandparent `LI`).

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/xnzs71d2/1/

```
$('.menu').delegate('li', 'click', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var thisId = this.id;
    alert(thisId);
});
```

In later version of jQuery use a delegated `on` instead

```
$('.menu').on('click', 'li', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var thisId = this.id;
    alert(thisId);
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/xnzs71d2/3/

Answer (score 0):

```
// jQuery 1.7+
$('.menu').on('click', 'li', function() {
  var thisId = this.id;
  alert(thisId);
});

// jQuery 1.4.3+
$('.menu').delegate('li', 'click', function() {
  var thisId = this.id;
  alert(thisId);
});
```

Comment: What is benefit of using on() insted of delegate()?